# How to update existing objects based on some conditions in Java 8 optional

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class CustomerDto {
    private Collection<PhoneDto> phones;
    //setters
    public Optional<Collection<PhoneDto>> getPhones() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(phones);
    }
}

class PhoneDto {
    String number;
    String type;
    //setters
    public Optional<String> getN
umber() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(number);
    }
    public Optional<String> getType() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(type);
    }
}
```

I have CustomerDto  contains list of PhoneDto's

Need to update if type is home and number is empty set default number 99999999999 in customerDto

```
PhoneDto phoneDto = new PhoneDto();
phoneDto.setNumber("");
phoneDto.setType("home");
PhoneDto phoneDto1 = new PhoneDto();
phoneDto1.setNumber("909090000");
phoneDto1.setType("office");
Collection<PhoneDto> list = new ArrayList();
list.add(phoneDto);
list.add(phoneDto1);
CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto();
customerDto.setPhones(list);
// Need to update if type is home and number is empty in customerDto
customerDto.getPhones().ifPresent(custDto -> {
    custDto.forEach(ph -> {
        if (ph.getType().equals("home") &&
        ph.getNumber().filter(String::isEmpty).isPresent()) {
            ph.setNumber("99999999999");
        }
    });
});
```

In output I am not getting updated value "99999999999". still getting old value.

Case :  number empty && type "home"
        update phone number to "99999999999"

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and give a check. You're not asking for anything in your post.

Comment: @Lutzi he's asking why the value of `phoneDto` is not updating.

Comment: Use if (ph.getType().orElse("notHome").equals("home")..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code you posted:

```java
ph.getType().equals("home")
```

Method `getType()` in class `PhoneDto` returns `Optional`.
Obviously `Optional` will never be equal to a `String`, will it?
You need to check if the `Optional` contains a value and if it does, extract the value and compare **that** with the `String` *home*.

Comment: Its working with this     if (ph.getType().get().equals("home")

Comment: @GSriHAri I remind you that method `get()` in class `Optional` throws `NoSuchElementException` if its value is null. Is that acceptable?